# Java text file werid output Format

Tags: java, text-files

I'm facing a weird problem when I use the method printf to write values into a text file using java , and the result is really bad ,I consulted some java documentation and it suggest I use the formatting

```
("%-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s  %-20s %-20s%n",
```

And the result is really not good

```
  for (int i=0 ; i<array.length ; i++)
   {   
       texfile.printf("%-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s  %-20s %-20s%n", array[i].getName().getName(), array[i].getTittle() , array[i].getCodeISBN() , array[i].getDate() ,array[i].getPrice() , array[i].getNum() );
       book++;
   }
```

[image]

what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like one of `getName().getName()` or `getTittle()` is returning a `String` with length greater than 20.  Characters beyond the specified width are not trimmed by [`java.io.PrintStream.printf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).  From the [`java.util.Formatter` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html): "The width is the minimum number of characters to be written to the output."

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the whitespaces with `trim()` method in String. try doing it with below approach. i assume that your `getters return Strings`.

```
 texfile.printf("%-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s  %-20s %-20s%n", array[i].getName().getName().trim(), array[i].getTittle().trim() , array[i].getCodeISBN().trim() , array[i].getDate().trim() ,array[i].getPrice().trim() , array[i].getNum().trim() );
```